# Implementing a Multidepth ExpandableList Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, multi-level

I am trying to display a multi-depth expandable list.  That is, we have a table with the header ID | School | Grade | Name

and I want to show an expandable list that has
School
   -  Grade
       - Name

Where the schools are the 1st depth, Grade's are the second depth, and the name is the leaf node.  I understand how to get the grade display, but I am unable to figure out how to do the additional leaf below it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, there is no more-than-two levels ExpendableList. However, from the [ExpandableListView](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/ExpandableListView.java) source, you should be able to make a custom class achieving what you need.